# React Formik: My custom onBlur override default touched behavior and not displaying my ErrorMessage

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik, yup

I just started learning to code 2 months ago, this week I tried to work with Formik and had this issue where I can't display my ErrorMessage after I added onBlur on the field, before added it, was working normally.

Also, I didn't find another way to work with onBlur, that's why I code it on the field.
I appreciate it if have a hand.

```
    import { Formik, Field, Form, ErrorMessage } from "formik";
    import Schema from "./Schema";
    import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";
    import { useState } from "react";
    import Result from "./Result";
    import { BsEyeSlashFill } from "react-icons/bs";
    
    const Register = () => {
      const [data, setData] = useState(false);
      const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false)
      const [showConfirmPassword, setConfirmShowPassword] = useState(false)
      const [checkMarkName, setCheckMarkName] = useState(null)
      const [checkMarkSurname, setCheckMarkSurname] = useState(false)
      const [checkMarkEmail, setCheckMarkEmail] = useState(false)
      const [checkMarkPass, setCheckMarkPass] = useState(false)
      const [checkMarkConfirmPass, setCheckMarkConfirmPass] = useState(false)
    
    
      const hidePassword = () => {
          setShowPassword(!showPassword)
      }
    
      const hideConfirmPassword = () => {
        setConfirmShowPassword(!showConfirmPassword)
    }
    
      function onSubmit(values, actions) {
        setData(values)
      }
    
      return (
        <Formik
          validationSchema={Schema}
          onSubmit={onSubmit}
          validateOnMount
          initialValues={{
            name: "",
            surname: "",
            email: "",
            password: "",
            confirmPassword: "",
          }}
        >
          {(props) => (
            <Container>
              <Row className="justify-content-center mt-3"  >
                <Col className="text-center d-flex justify-content-center" md={8}>
                  <Form className="mt-5 div-form w-100">
                    {console.log(props)}
                    <div className="errors mt-3">
                      <label>Nome</label>
                      <Field onBlur={() => {
                          if(!props.errors.name)(
                              setCheckMarkName(true)
                          )
                          }} name="name" className={checkMarkName ? "form-control form-control-green" : "form-control"} type="text" />
                      <div><ErrorMessage name="name" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="errors mt-3">
                      <label>Surname</label>
                      <Field onBlur={() => {
                          if(!props.errors.surname)(
                              setCheckMarkSurname(true)
                          )
                          }} name="surname" className={checkMarkSurname ? "form-control form-control-green" : "form-control"} type="text" />
                      <div><ErrorMessage name="surname" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="errors mt-3">
                      <label>Email</label>
                      <Field onBlur={() => {
                          if(!props.errors.email)(
                              setCheckMarkEmail(true)
                          )
                          }} name="email" className={checkMarkEmail ? "form-control form-control-green" : "form-control"} type="email" />
                      <div><ErrorMessage name="email" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="errors mt-3 position-relative">
                      <label>Password</label>
                      <Field onBlur={() => {
                          if(!props.errors.password)(
                              setCheckMarkPass(true)
                          )
                          }}
                        name="password"
                        className={checkMarkPass ? "form-control form-control-green" : "form-control"}
                        type={showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
                      ></Field>
                      <span className="position-relative eyes text-white"><BsEyeSlashFill onClick={() => hidePassword()} /></span>
                      <div className="position-relative error-msg"><ErrorMessage name="password" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="errors mb-4 position-relative">
                      <label>Confirm Password</label>
                      <Field onBlur={() => {
                          if(!props.errors.confirmPassword)(
                              setCheckMarkConfirmPass(true)
                          )
                          }}
                        name="confirmPassword"
                        className={checkMarkConfirmPass ? "form-control form-control-green" : "form-control"}
                        type={showConfirmPassword ? 'text' : 'password'}
                      />
                      <span className="position-relative eyesConfirm text-white"><BsEyeSlashFill onClick={() => hideConfirmPassword()} /></span>
                      <div className="position-relative error-msg"><ErrorMessage name="confirmPassword" /></div>
                    </div>
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-primary mb-3"
                      disabled={!props.isValid}
                      type="submit"
                    >
                      Enviar
                    </button>
                    <button
                      className="btn btn-primary mb-3 ml-3"
                      type="button"
                      onClick={() => setData(false)}
                    >
                      Reset
                    </button>
                  </Form>
                </Col>
                {
                data &&
                <Result data={data}/>
                }
              </Row>
            </Container>
          )}
        </Formik>
      );
    };
    
    export default Register;
```